# Shopware 6 custom plugin, deleting extension on delete parent does not work

Tags: plugins, shopware6

I have an extension created following the manual [Adding complex data to existing entities](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities).
My product has with this extension another property like e.g `product_color`. On delete the product the prop (entity table) `product_color` still remains in the database.

```
// Migration%123%ProductColor.php

...
    public function update(Connection $connection): void
    {
        $sql = <<<SQL
CREATE TABLE `product_color` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
SQL;
        $connection->executeStatement($sql);
    }
...
```

**EDIT #1**
As recommend by @Alex, i've added flags, but **the extension keep in the database**:

```
// custom/plugins/MyPlugin/src/Extension/ProductColor/ProductColorExtension.php

class ProductColorExtension extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection
            ->add(
                (new OneToOneAssociationField(
                'productColor',
                'id',
                'product_id',
                ProductColorExtensionDefinition::class,
                true
            ))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete())
            );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return ProductDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

Questions:

- how to make the additional property deletable on delete its parent ([delete cascade](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/))?
- where are the corresponding manual how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to setting the `CascadeDelete` flag in the entity definition, you need to add a foreign key constraint with your database migration and use `CASCADE` for the `ON DELETE` subclause.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `product_color` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk.product_color.product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: adding a FK to an order extension tableresults in this error when making an order in the storefront:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sw6`.`my_order_extension`, CONSTRAINT `FK__my_order_extension_order_id` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `order` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Is this a bug in sw6 or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There [is a flag](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/core-reference/dal-reference/flags-reference) `CascadeDelete` which you can add to your association field:

```
->addFlags(new CascadeDelete())
```

This should lead to an `ON DELETE CASCADE` entry in the SQL, if you create it
with [dal:create:schema](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/database-migrations#sql-schema).

Comment: Thx for your reply, but still not work...see my EDIT #1